# Remove Data From An ImportHTML Query In Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

So I'm trying to import a dataset from Fulltimefantasy.com. I've managed to find a query that helped accomplish this goal. However, there are 2 "problems" in what's returned.

```
={QUERY(IMPORTXML("http://play.fulltimefantasy.com/avgdraftDFWC.php","//tr | //td/a/@title"),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"),QUERY(IMPORTXML("http://play.fulltimefantasy.com/avgdraftDFWC.php","//tr"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7")}
```

Cell A1, where the code resides, displays a gnarly amount of text.

```
"Visit our Expert Draft Reviews from the Top Ranked Players in the World. Average Draft Position ----- Based on the 63 Dynasty League 
Redrafts.#NamePosTmAvgHighLow<-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------DFWC 
LEAGUE # 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->12345678910Name11121314151617181920Name21222324252627282930Name31323334353637383940Name41424344454647484950Name515253545556575859606162631EdwardsHelaire,ClydeRBKC1.891222211112121EdwardsHelaire,Clyde2113122111EdwardsHelaire,Clyde1111111221EdwardsHelaire,Clyde1211221122EdwardsHelaire,Clyde1222112121EdwardsHelaire,Clyde2111121111112142Taylor,JonathanRBIND2.171241122221212Taylor,Jonathan1231211222Taylor,Jonathan2222222112Taylor,Jonathan2122112211Taylor,Jonathan2111221212Taylor,Jonathan1222212222221133Dobbins,J.K.RBBAL4.863365444654853Dobbins,J.K.3544335335Dobbins,J.K.4444433445Dobbins,J.K.3363335536Dobbins,J.K.6633543433Dobbins,J.K.6335433443445244Swift,DAndreRBDET5.022393535343345Swift,DAndre4462443543Swift,DAndre3335355534Swift,DAndre5475546648Swift,DAndre3344434344Swift,DAndre5443354534353305Akers,CamRBLAR5.773424353435437Akers,Cam5355564474Akers,Cam5553644353Akers,Cam4744754357Akers,Cam4455356556Akers,Cam7754576355536356Lamb,CeeDeeWRDAL7.523527676767576Lamb,CeeDee8676657656Lamb,CeeDee6676587767Lamb,CeeDee6558477773Lamb,CeeDee81067667767Lamb,CeeDee4576747667769367Jeudy,JerryWRDEN7.582486789576664Jeudy,Jerry7728776767Jeudy,Jerry7767766676Jeudy,Jerry7637663494Jeudy,Jerry7986778875Jeudy,Jerry3668965776684448Vaughn,KeShawnRBTB10.9756410126788912108Vaughn,KeShawn61110131081211910Vaughn,KeShawn1011101089109118Vaughn,KeShawn89116118911811Vaughn,KeShawn957119856911Vaughn,KeShawn1110898101011151016128539Jefferson,JustinWRMIN11568891010101110989Jefferson,Justin10899991010811Jefferson,Justin912118107981010Jefferson,Justin911991011109119Jefferson,Justin5791010111191010Jefferson,Justin9811116889891011106810Reagor,JalenWRPHI11.4577111812811987913Reagor,Jalen11987111089109Reagor,Jalen88149121081099Reagor,Jalen1181011991181210Reagor,Jalen101210989912128Reagor,Jalen8910101311128101287117111Ruggs,HenryWRLV11.49563910111291011101215Ruggs,Henry912131081398138Ruggs,Henry12981111141112811Ruggs,Henry101081081081065Ruggs,Henry1181181210101089Ruggs,Henry1011127129111098111075612Pittman,MichaelWRIND15.6599513141313121314131611Pittman,Michael15161117131213121412Pittman,Michael1115131291313131316Pittman,Michael14141214131214121016Pittman,Michael12131212111512111414Pittman,Michael12141412171715151313179169513Mims,DenzelWRNYJ17.141111114111516141613111312Mims,Denzel12171611151114141516Mims,Denzel13161613151916161212Mims,Denzel12121513161313151713Mims,Denzel13151315131315151812Mims,Denzel1616151511131320141418151510314Higgins,TeeWRCIN17.221111716131615171212161517Higgins,Tee14151415161411131218Higgins,Tee15131516141515141414Higgins,Tee13131317141612141512Higgins,Tee14141516141420141615Higgins,Tee181513131414171211151314178915Moss,ZackRBBUF17.9491121517918131418141416Moss,Zack18201214141618191115Moss,Zack20181218191114201920Moss,Zack17231612121817131415Moss,Zack15111813171214191116Moss,Zack17181917101519191611917127616Aiyuk,BrandonWRSF18.68910617161714151719151910Aiyuk,Brandon17101516121516151613Aiyuk,Brandon2317914181817181518Aiyuk,Brandon19192018181720201818Aiyuk,Brandon16171917151617131713Aiyuk,Brandon1312161418121617171614131310617Dillon,AJRBGB20.171012912151922161516191718Dillon,AJ13192212181822171817Dillon,AJ16102115261212111721Dillon,AJ15151416251923161319Dillon,AJ18211618201721171518Dillon,AJ212121191516221312171518189218Shenault,LaviskaWRJAC21.081212818181819191815172019Shenault,Laviska19132018191719161719Shenault,Laviska25141917161719151622Shenault,Laviska18171919171516212220Shenault,Laviska19181414182018181920Shenault,Laviska1422172119241818181812201410719Burrow,JoeQBCIN21.68911421221421221925201814Burrow,Joe16181922172426202014Burrow,Joe17201822132718222113Burrow,Joe21242315211418172114Burrow,Joe17232120162319222022Burrow,Joe191391623181416191921162511420Gibson,AntonioRBWAS24.451314019192220252022222225Gibson,Antonio21141821222117212121Gibson,Antonio19221724231620172617Gibson,Antonio25161723222115191917Gibson,Antonio24202323231813162923Gibson,Antonio2624181826232425242422242114021Edwards,BryanWRLV26.861716726202417262423212324Edwards,Bryan24222119211921181923Edwards,Bryan27332025212022212225Edwards,Bryan26182521202229232022Edwards,Bryan32222024192124212221Edwards,Bryan2227232428252724252123222214322McFarland,AnthonyRBPIT27.41514122232323212224262622McFarland,Anthony29212427252325352425McFarland,Anthony22262521222521233424McFarland,Anthony16252728153124222525McFarland,Anthony26291721222222252327McFarland,Anthony2923252324212321232919232014123Evans,DarryntonRBTEN27.651112424252111282520303223Evans,Darrynton25243138232515292832Evans,Darrynton21342728292127192826Evans,Darrynton23222126272321281623Evans,Darrynton20272419291925202432Evans,Darrynton2326282516203022273326261912424Claypool,ChaseWRPIT28.981616323212927292621253321Claypool,Chase23342325282724312720Claypool,Chase26252419202423272323Claypool,Chase20201830282030253126Claypool,Chase29162731242531323224Claypool,Chase2032202620272023283027252612725Tagovailoa,TuaQBMIA29.58916036282728232729232128Tagovailoa,Tua26272920203436263722Tagovailoa,Tua18282823173225242527Tagovailoa,Tua22292232262625182324Tagovailoa,Tua22263030212723362733Tagovailoa,Tua281932303019931212033192812826Kelley,JoshuaRBLAC30.661315435292824343027242427Kelley,Joshua27282823312620302926Kelley,Joshua28242329282228252037Kelley,Joshua27262936192722272729Kelley,Joshua21192525352426231330Kelley,Joshua3529273636222539262325312913227Hamler,KJWRDEN33.352017225273126273231332831Hamler,KJ22333028333028332528Hamler,KJ32213020352324313128Hamler,KJ29332420233928344421Hamler,KJ28252946263130302826Hamler,KJ2540303222263134362530293017228Duvernay,DevinWRBAL35.982016929353638203941272532Duvernay,Devin36393326273134283531Duvernay,Devin24373226383026372730Duvernay,Devin30353724302431383834Duvernay,Devin25363234324332383331Duvernay,Devin4336244129302636292632352715029Jefferson,VanWRLAR36.082218640383429243133362935Jefferson,Van31312630244233222634Jefferson,Van34384027312934293729Jefferson,Van28323122363327353627Jefferson,Van31332228343729333029Jefferson,Van2730363432313430303231334116930GandyGolden,AntonioWRWAS38.662318433443044392339382740GandyGolden,Antonio35384334293923253327GandyGolden,Antonio33393432483539333639GandyGolden,Antonio24274434573239374128GandyGolden,Antonio35382839314033354228GandyGolden,Antonio3033313531392933323524303614831Benjamin,EnoRBARI38.982519638313725373332353630Benjamin,Eno33433941303232383938Benjamin,Eno39303331302829423233Benjamin,Eno32303329422938314342Benjamin,Eno43413844413027272534Benjamin,Eno3339294038353941343441323114732Perine,LamicalRBNYJ41.522123131343340352130403026Perine,Lamical30403639353331373033Perine,Lamical44314336343443363834Perine,Lamical36393662314432293343Perine,Lamical34303640333238393535Perine,Lamical3644434535433735493634382319633Dallas,DeeJayRBSEA42.062619947393234323437323534Dallas,DeeJay37373440383637323236Dallas,DeeJay444240453338323931Dallas,DeeJay37373256333535403244Dallas,DeeJay44283929402628294738Dallas,DeeJay3253423346473642443742273918534Johnson,TylerWRTB43.342221537533939313734394736Johnson,Tyler42362736324530345837Johnson,Tyler55492935404041473041Johnson,Tyler33383838373440395633Johnson,Tyler30353747364134284125Johnson,Tyler4735352837332845352248463421535Kmet,ColeTECHI44.342320741304462303649344343Kmet,Cole28483243363535234358Kmet,Cole36324641322630404446Kmet,Cole38454242325041304036Kmet,Cole37324832423842264336Kmet,Cole4250374742453337412851493719836Cephus,QuintezWRDET44.382820950334764544552414638Cephus,Quintez50424435464342403849Cephus,Quintez31353934393646452970Cephus,Quintez35343439504043463441Cephus,Quintez38393554463637343757Cephus,Quintez41313446472845443339434420937Bowden,LynnRBLV45.582822645373536404436373733Bowden,Lynn41303537413738433641Bowden,Lynn38404737363135304335Bowden,Lynn39284147493647414931Bowden,Lynn42344135372840413637Bowden,Lynn3151415261383843376140486821838Herbert,JustinQBLAC47.032019542484949415747454547Herbert,Justin48445732435343475440Herbert,Justin603739425944535436Herbert,Justin44545449355858324548Herbert,Justin39543452274449425340Herbert,Justin3820464439413259384135343519539Anderson,DariusRBDAL48.53364Anderson,DariusAnderson,Darius64Anderson,DariusAnderson,DariusAnderson,Darius3340Calais,RaymondRBTB51.672672464935684456Calais,Raymond526855634544Calais,Raymond52556156535640Calais,Raymond72545568Calais,Raymond51265843403147Calais,Raymond37454850555863476941Trautman,AdamTENO51.922923943325747443846425541Trautman,Adam45454042344139464568Trautman,Adam58295052416136494047Trautman,Adam31425341605644434237Trautman,Adam426833673947503439Trautman,Adam50454748434443704746455823942Mack,AustinWRNYG53535353Mack,AustinMack,AustinMack,AustinMack,AustinMack,Austin43PeoplesJones,DonovanWRCLE53.533423254404550514361484837PeoplesJones,Donovan57574553485549424146PeoplesJones,Donovan40654155444370594145PeoplesJones,Donovan436651403856485240PeoplesJones,Donovan53574556476848453946PeoplesJones,Donovan3442495845373538533839504621944Reed,JoeWRLAC53.82377152463757Reed,Joe6470576369Reed,Joe464771644948656050Reed,Joe415052624770564663Reed,Joe504560496838Reed,Joe54524162374145Asiasi,DevinTENE54.053824162425959604250694045Asiasi,Devin51515451393848554443Asiasi,Devin694652435047544743Asiasi,Devin52513951716065555153Asiasi,Devin46474064396445615249Asiasi,Devin5338484954484253464671703824146Hill,K.J.WRLAC54.58387150705240523870Hill,K.J.54603861615851Hill,K.J.51466563Hill,K.J.5855715962Hill,K.J.525960664144Hill,K.J.48586753494942495247Keene,DaltonTENE54.84959Keene,DaltonKeene,DaltonKeene,Dalton545956Keene,Dalton49Keene,Dalton5648Jones,XavierRBLAR555555Jones,XavierJones,XavierJones,XavierJones,XavierJones,Xavier5549Davis,GabrielWRBUF55.47387267634658495157Davis,Gabriel586971464950554562Davis,Gabriel48386951405146Davis,Gabriel4552457268526555Davis,Gabriel4066634567464965Davis,Gabriel6760595566656348455650Hodgins,IsaiahWRBUF55.73407171Hodgins,Isaiah61Hodgins,IsaiahHodgins,Isaiah6364Hodgins,Isaiah614848Hodgins,Isaiah565061455358574051Okwuegbunam,AlbertTEDEN55.7440726748474855655068Okwuegbunam,Albert686657475057Okwuegbunam,Albert70485850625072Okwuegbunam,Albert426564486069Okwuegbunam,Albert475666586045Okwuegbunam,Albert44514449406366534852Proche,JamesWRBAL55.8540725559Proche,James6667477165Proche,James566656604267Proche,James49474654605972Proche,James415755595965Proche,James466940484060425453Johnson,CollinWRJAC564269534858Johnson,Collin6154525756Johnson,Collin56636855Johnson,Collin564252Johnson,Collin6954Johnson,Collin5758466154Watkins,QuezWRPHI57.41437052Watkins,Quez50Watkins,Quez646652Watkins,Quez536459Watkins,Quez5245Watkins,Quez5864706666524355Mooney,DarnellWRCHI57.54317068635359Mooney,Darnell696870Mooney,Darnell544370545664Mooney,Darnell66665633616465Mooney,Darnell333154Mooney,Darnell445165646756Bryant,HarrisonTECLE57.79447170Bryant,Harrison596755Bryant,Harrison576457Bryant,Harrison5544Bryant,Harrison60495051Bryant,Harrison7157Dowdle,RicoRBDAL58536464Dowdle,RicoDowdle,Rico53Dowdle,RicoDowdle,Rico57Dowdle,Rico58Taylor,PatrickRBGB58.5585959Taylor,PatrickTaylor,Patrick58Taylor,PatrickTaylor,PatrickTaylor,Patrick59Ahmed,SalvonRBSF58.5540685767Ahmed,Salvon40Ahmed,Salvon54Ahmed,Salvon6759606468Ahmed,Salvon44Ahmed,Salvon6460Robinson,JamesRBJAC58.583621665554655567054Robinson,James496452407245Robinson,James56485969654469Robinson,James66474846456945Robinson,James5743515863Robinson,James6655605036444521661Warren,MichaelRBPHI58.9237725646636066Warren,Michael564857646746616669Warren,Michael676362685562Warren,Michael68727037Warren,Michael5943425364Warren,Michael5565546652546562Huntley,JasonRBDET5944696659Huntley,Jason44Huntley,JasonHuntley,Jason53Huntley,Jason69Huntley,Jason546863Coulter,IsaiahWRHOU59.15467253637158Coulter,Isaiah67496152Coulter,Isaiah58635258Coulter,Isaiah466857Coulter,Isaiah7262Coulter,Isaiah64515864Leake,JavonRBNYG59.67357267Leake,JavonLeake,JavonLeake,Javon506435Leake,JavonLeake,Javon707265Deguara,JosiahTEGB60417166Deguara,Josiah41Deguara,Josiah61Deguara,Josiah7169Deguara,Josiah4567Deguara,Josiah66Hightower,JohnWRPHI60.124372596072Hightower,John5566546264Hightower,John525768Hightower,John4866716662Hightower,John564361645060Hightower,John6067685267Phillips,ScottieRBHOU60.3356665956Phillips,ScottiePhillips,ScottiePhillips,ScottiePhillips,Scottie66Phillips,Scottie68Hopkins,BrycenTELAR60.33546954Hopkins,Brycen58Hopkins,Brycen69Hopkins,BrycenHopkins,BrycenHopkins,Brycen69Moss,ThaddeusTEWAS60.9525725468Moss,Thaddeus686060Moss,Thaddeus25506355Moss,Thaddeus64655166577068Moss,Thaddeus715970Moss,Thaddeus726470Taylor,J.J.RBNE61606262Taylor,J.J.Taylor,J.J.60Taylor,J.J.Taylor,J.J.Taylor,J.J.71Begelton,ReggieWRGB616161Begelton,ReggieBegelton,ReggieBegelton,ReggieBegelton,ReggieBegelton,Reggie6172Thomas,JeffWRNE61.74472476244Thomas,Jeff71Thomas,Jeff6569Thomas,JeffThomas,Jeff6370Thomas,Jeff547273Bryant,HunterTEDET62.55570Bryant,Hunter70Bryant,HunterBryant,HunterBryant,Hunter55Bryant,Hunter74Rohrwasser,JustinPKNE62.56164Rohrwasser,JustinRohrwasser,JustinRohrwasser,JustinRohrwasser,Justin61Rohrwasser,Justin6475Jennings,JauanWRSF63527070Jennings,JauanJennings,Jauan63Jennings,Jauan67Jennings,Jauan52Jennings,Jauan76Hasty,JaMycalRBSF64.55570666155Hasty,JaMycal616470Hasty,JaMycal69Hasty,JaMycal70Hasty,JaMycalHasty,JaMycal77Blankenship,RodrigoPKIND65.33616861Blankenship,RodrigoBlankenship,RodrigoBlankenship,RodrigoBlankenship,Rodrigo67Blankenship,Rodrigo6878Eason,JacobQBIND666567Eason,Jacob67Eason,Jacob66Eason,JacobEason,JacobEason,Jacob6579Love,JordanQBGB66.133123557676171Love,Jordan59695650Love,Jordan3149Love,Jordan4957524842Love,Jordan44506455Love,Jordan49666860484360516423580Swain,FreddieWRSEA676767Swain,FreddieSwain,FreddieSwain,FreddieSwain,Freddie67Swain,Freddie81Callaway,MarquezWRNO686868Callaway,Marquez68Callaway,Marquez68Callaway,MarquezCallaway,MarquezCallaway,Marquez82Hurts,JalenQBPHI68.223923662617152635772Hurts,Jalen60715252Hurts,Jalen726256Hurts,Jalen575058606739Hurts,Jalen48657049536571Hurts,Jalen697058476144724223683Lipscomb,KalijaWRKC696969Lipscomb,Kalija69Lipscomb,KalijaLipscomb,KalijaLipscomb,Kalija69Lipscomb,Kalija84Feaster,TavienRBJAC70707070Feaster,TavienFeaster,TavienFeaster,TavienFeaster,TavienFeaster,Tavien85Johnson,JuwanWRNO717171Johnson,JuwanJohnson,JuwanJohnson,Juwan71Johnson,JuwanJohnson,Juwan86Pierce,ArtavisRBCHI223223223Pierce,ArtavisPierce,ArtavisPierce,ArtavisPierce,ArtavisPierce,Artavis223 Average Draft Position ----- Based on the 63 Dynasty League Redrafts. #"
```

Problem 2 is with Row 2 - it displays 1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in the respective columns. So row 1 is the header row i'd expect and row 3 has data i'd expect.

So how do i remove row 2 and cell A1 from the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={{""; QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "http://play.fulltimefantasy.com/avgdraftDFWC.php", "//tr | //td/a/@title"),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null"),
 "offset 2", 0)}, QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "http://play.fulltimefantasy.com/avgdraftDFWC.php", "//tr"),
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7"), 
 "where not Col1 = '2'")}
```

[image]